# Storing hexadecimal representation of int at std::vector of unsigned char

Tags: c++, vector, hex, unsigned-char

In this code:

```
  vector<unsigned char> result;
  int n;
  unsigned char c;

  c = (n >> 24) & 0xFF;
  result.push_back(c);
  c = (n >> 16) & 0xFF;
  result.push_back(c);
  c = (n >> 8) & 0xFF;
  result.push_back(c);
  c = n & 0xFF;
  result.push_back(c);
```

I want, instead of add one single byte to the vector (`c`), add each digit of the hexadecimal representation of the integer `n` (like `FF` for something like `0xFF`).

Anyone can give a hint of how to accomplish that?

**update**

I update my code to this, which works with most values except 0 and 1 (the hexadecimal representation stays with one digit and one space: "0 " and "1 ").

```
  BYTE c;

  vector<BYTE> v_version;
  c = (version >> 24) & 0xFF;
  v_version.push_back(c);
  c = (version >> 16) & 0xFF;
  v_version.push_back(c);
  c = (version >> 8) & 0xFF;
  v_version.push_back(c);
  c = version & 0xFF;
  v_version.push_back(c);

  for (auto c: v_version)
  {
    ostringstream oss;
    oss << hex << static_cast<int>(c);
    result.push_back( oss.str()[0] );
    result.push_back( oss.str()[1] );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`n` is uninitialized so first take care of that.

Depending on what your ultimately goal is the best solution is not to store the hex digits, but to keep the current binary representation and just print in hex. To do that you need `std::hex` and an integer cast:

```
std::cout << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0');
std::cout << static_cast<unsigned>(c);
```

If you want to store the result instead of printing it you can do it with `ostringstream` like in your example. But I strongly suggest `std::string` or `std::vector<char>`. Despite its name `unsigned char` should not be used with characters. If you have characters like here the underlying type should be `char`.

- use `char` for characters
- use `unsigned char` for raw memory (byte)
- don't use `signed char`

Comment: I don't need display the value (with `cout`); I have a struct with elements of type `int` and `string` (the example show the `int`element, the `string` already is a hexadecimal representation) and need generate a vector of unsigned char as return value for the method.

Comment: @KleberMota then why does your question show something completely different? Please [edit] your question with code that you actually have and with what you actually want to do. Nowhere in your question do you mention an existing `string`

Comment: the string is not relevant here, i just want convert the `int` to  its hexadecimal representation. the code in the question is what i am using right now, and want adjust to get the desired result.

Comment: and how do you want to store this? (in what type?)

Comment: like show in the code presented in the question, i push each character to the vector `result`.

Comment: @KleberMota I am genuinely confused. There is a misunderstanding somewhere. Let us try and figure it out: You are correctly storing the binary representation of `n` into a `vector<unsigned char>`. Now you say you want to store the "hexadecimal representation". This can only be a string. You can store that in a `std::string`. A `vector<unsigned char>` is not a proper storage for a string.

Comment: see the update with the modified code, maybe could easier to understand the final goal.

Comment: do you know how to solve the issue with the characters '0' and '1'?

Comment: @KleberMota I showed you in the edit: use `setw` and `setfill`